# ASP.NET: Execute MSBuild tasks after publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have an ASP.NET project.
There is a 'Publish...' option in the context menu of the project (Visual Studio 2008).

Can I add some custom MSBuild tasks that will be performed each time after publishing?

If not, what is the best way to write MSBuild script that will publish the project (the same way as 'Publish...' option) and then execute my custom tasks?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solution answers the second question: http://codingcockerel.co.uk/?p=15. You can easily add the custom tasks to the publish target.

Comment: This link is redirecting to spam/porn.